# How to deploy Unity 3d app on AWS or other cloud platform

Tags: amazon-web-services, unity-game-engine, cloud

This is a general question about cloud architecture. I have a unity 3d app that I am able to deploy as a standalone app for PC or Mac. But I would like to deploy it over the web so that users can access it by logging into a website. The user should be able to use a typical web browser on their laptop of desktop to access this app.

My app isn't a game and isn't physics intensive. It is a simple visualization tool for viewing architectural designs. Is there a way to use AWS or GCE to distribute my app? Do I absolutely need make user of of Unity's "Master Server"?

I also want to take "continuous integration" into consideration. So if I update the code repository and publish it to the production server all users should see the new graphical content while their personal data is accessed from a database (AWS RDS or AWS DynamoDB)

What type of basic steps do I need to follow for my requirements if I am using Amazon Web Services to deploy my Unity 3d App?

For example, would I need to setup a web server that allows users to access the unity3d app via a socket while the app is constantly running? How do I manage different sessions and different users?

Any help or links to online resources would be helpful. I tried looking but couldn't find a schematic for the app architecture.

I am also happy to use Google Compute Engine instead of AWS if there is a tutorial for it.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couldn't you just export the application to HTML using Unity's Web Player?
http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/WebPlayerDeployment.html

This way all you would need is a web server really, and you could configure that on any VPS.